# Working with bitmaps to a ZPL label printer

Tags: vb.net, bitmapdata, bmp, zebra-printers, zpl

```
    Dim bitmapFilePath As String = imagepath here...
    Dim bitmapFileData As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(bitmapFilePath)
    Dim fileSize As Integer = bitmapFileData.Length

    Dim bitmapDataOffset As Integer = 0
    Dim width As Integer = 50 '255
    Dim height As Integer = 50 '255
    Dim bitsPerPixel As Integer = 1
    Dim bitmapDataLength As Integer = 400
    Dim widthInBytes As Double = Math.Ceiling(width / 8.0)

    Dim bitmap(bitmapDataLength) As Byte
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bitmapFileData, bitmapDataOffset, bitmap, 0, bitmapDataLength)


    For i As Integer = 0 To bitmapDataLength Step 1
        bitmap(i) = bitmap(i) Xor &HFF

    Next

    Dim ZPLImageDataString As String = BitConverter.ToString(bitmap)
    ZPLImageDataString = Replace(ZPLImageDataString, "-", String.Empty)

    Dim zplCommand(3) As String

    zplCommand(0) = "^XA"
    zplCommand(1) = "^FO20,20"
    zplCommand(2) =
    "^GFA, " +
    bitmapDataLength.ToString() + "," +
    bitmapDataLength.ToString() + "," +
    widthInBytes.ToString() + "," +
    ZPLImageDataString

    zplCommand(3) = "^XZ"
```

It prints out a nonsense square that looks like someone applied the noise filter in Photoshop. I found this solution on the Zebra website, but that image was 255/255, I need this for a 50/50 image, but I have no idea what I'm supposed to change the offset to or the bitmapDatalength...

Comment: What is your source file? The code looks like it is expecting pure binary image data with no headers.

Comment: It's a .BMP image, nothing special... http://imgur.com/SsxCL (I think imgur changed it into a png though

Answer (score 1):

Is your bitmap 1-bit color depth? You can't send color images like this, they need to be converted to b/w 1-bit per pixel.  You also need to make sure that your `bitmapDataLength` variable is correct.  This should be the *number of bytes of the image* to be sent to the printer.  See the `^GF` command in the [ZPL Manual](http://www.ptshome.com/kb/Manuals/ZPL_Vol1.pdf).  You can also look in the manual at the example after the ~DG command if you want to save the image on your printer

If you just need to convert a couple images and save them off, you can use the *Graphics Conversion Wizard* in [**ZebraNet Bridge**](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/manage-software/zebranet-bridge-enterprise.html). It will take care of the color conversion, and ZPL ^GF math for you and you can also optioinally store the image on your printer.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm just going to go with the ZebraNet Bridge and call the templates from there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problema and solved like this. technically, don't know how, but try it...

`Dim bitmapDataLength As Integer = 338` 
 `Dim bitmapDataOffset As Integer = 62`

The first line represents the image size (file size)in bytes - 62
The second line represents the image's header size (62)

Hope this helps

Comment: I actually got the above solution to work, but I've jotted down that the header size is 62. I think that's what I was doing wrong.